# change primary key values

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

Okay, so I'm not sure if this is possible but I need to change the primary key values in one table to match the FK values in another table.

What had happened is I created one table - POS_Transactions (FK REGISTER) - and imported its values, and then I created another table - Registers (pk REGISTERS_KEY) - and imported its values. But when I was importing the values for Registers, I came across some issues and had to clear the table and try it again multiple times (which is why the numbers go from 15-22, it just automatically updated that way) but I need them to say 1-8 so that it still connects to POS_Transactions.

Is there any way that I can change that?? And if so how do I do that? Sorry if that sounds stupid but I'm still new to SQL and I'm kind of stuck on what to do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That does help me with resetting the identity, so thank you, but it won't allow me to truncate the table since it's being referenced as a FK restraint.

Comment: You need to drop the FK constraint first.

Comment: I was able to fix it, thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `Truncate table` and try again.

You need to reset the `Identity` column.